# fopen dynamic file names

Tags: c, fopen

I am using mingw32 I want to create dynamic file names when I am creating files with fprint. I am reading data from an array and I would like to dynamically create string to use as the file name. I would think that I would be able to use sprintf to create the strings and pass the char array with the string in it to fopen; however, that doesn't seem to be working. This is what I would expect I would have to do:

```
unsigned char filename[64];
serial_write_slow("mV\r");
serial_read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &len);
tokenize_string(buffer, "\n");

sprintf(filename,"%s.csv",token_buf[0]);

FILE *myfile;
myfile = fopen(filename,"w");
```

mV is a command to a micro controller to get the firmware number  and I am reading and parsing the data into an array and torenize_string returns a char array containing the data I want to put in the string. I don't know if fopen is able to do this or not.

Comment: You should probably use `snprintf`, which does bounds checking.

Comment: What is `token_buf`?

Comment: Have you tried `printf("Filename = %s\n", filename);` to make sure the filename you are expecting is actually the one you are using?

Comment: snprintf is giving me a inter from pointer without a cast warning

Comment: token_buf is a string of char

Comment: got it, the string was containing a character that couldn't be used  for file names

Comment: this parameter: token_buf[0] is getting the value of a single character.  what is needs to get is a pointer and since token_buf is obviously an array (you should include the declarations for any variables used in a question, for clarity) the parameter should be: token_buf or &token_buf[0]